# how to change state object from api server in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to change object state from api server.

object state value from api server is like this:

```
29: {id: 29, memo_id: 1, name: "carrot", created_at: "2020-10-14T02:34:41.000000Z", updated_at: "2020-10-14T02:34:41.000000Z"}
30: {id: 30, memo_id: 1, name: "spinach", created_at: "2020-10-14T02:34:48.000000Z", updated_at: "2020-10-14T02:34:48.000000Z"}
```

I try to create updateValue function. but I don't change this.state.vegetableListsFromApiServer.name

Please tell me that how to change this.state.vegetableListsFromApiServer.name

thank you.

```
class VegetableShow extends Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            vegetableListsFromApiServer: nextProps.vegetableLists
        });
    }

    updateValue(e) {
        e.persist();
             this.setState(prevState => ({
                 ...prevState.vegetableListsFromApiServer,
                 name: e.target.value
            }));
    }

    renderShowVegetableList() {
        return _.map(this.state.vegetableListsFromApiServer, vegetableList => (
            <React.Fragment key={vegetableList.id}>
                <TextField
                    className="mt-5"
                    value={vegetableList.name}
                    onChange={this.updateValue}
                />
                <Button
                    className="mt-5 ml-3"
                    variant="contained"
                    color="secondary"
                    data-vegetable={vegetableList.id}
                    onClick={this.deleteVegetable}
                >
                    delete
                </Button>
            </React.Fragment>
        ));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="text-center">
                <h5 className="mt-5">vegetable list</h5>
                <TextField
                    className="mt-3"
                    value={this.state.vegetableList}
                    onChange={this.onVegetableListChange}
                />
                <Button
                    className="mt-3 ml-3"
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={this.postVegetable}
                >
                    delete
                </Button>
                {this.renderShowVegetableList()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of context but change this `_.map(this.state.vegetableListsFromApiServer, vegetableList => ())`; to `this.state.vegetableListsFromApiServer.map(vegetableList => ())`. You do not need to use `lodash` for mapping into an array. Array already has a map method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Pass the index of the array as the second argument to the update value method.
2. Update the name value by using an index to extract the value from the array.

```
updateValue(e, idx) {
    e.persist();
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const newArray = [...prevState.vegetableListsFromApiServer],
      newArray[idx].name = e.target.value;
      this.setState({ vegetableListsFromApiServer: newArray });
    })
  }


renderShowVegetableList() {
  return this.state.vegetableListsFromApiServer.map((vegetableList, idx) => (
      <React.Fragment key={vegetableList.id}>
          <TextField
              className="mt-5"
              value={vegetableList.name}
              onChange={(e) => this.updateValue(e, idx)}
          />
          <Button
              className="mt-5 ml-3"
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              data-vegetable={vegetableList.id}
              onClick={this.deleteVegetable}
          >
              delete
          </Button>
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. I could resolve my issue.
I am glad to resolve it.
thanks you very much.